# Entity Framework code first create column not mapped to property

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm using Entity Framework code first approach, configured using Fluent API.  I'd like to configure a particular table to have a column that I don't need as a property on the associated entity.  I know it's easy to do it the other way around: have a property on the entity that isn't mapped to a column on the database (simply using `Ignore`).  I can't find any way to configure the Fluent API config to have it create a column in the table for a property that doesn't exist on the entity though.

Perhaps it can't be done via Fluent API in which case, does anyone have any other ideas?  I think you can execute custom SQL so perhaps I could just execute SQL to add the column, but of course would only want it to run when the table is first created, not on subsequent migrations.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is possible, kinda defies the purpose of an entity mapper ;)

Comment: Well you can always use the `Sql()` function to add this column in your initial migration. Fluent API is only used for mapping, but you don't want this column mapped, so no need for it.